# For each row in a df, extract the observation which has the nearest value

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my sample data:

```
  iso3c production reported_by_FAO
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          
 1 NOR    10740117. Yes            
 2 TKM    10726360. No             
 3 SYR    10559247. Yes            
 4 ISR    10317065. No            
 5 DOM    10152261. No            
 6 TJK     9741324. Yes            
 7 YEM     9554599. No
```

I want to `mutate` a new column that shows the iso3c that is reported by FAO (ie reported_by_FAO == "Yes") which has the nearest production value for each row.

Using the sample data created above, this is what the output would look like.

```
  iso3c production reported_by_FAO nearest_iso3c
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <chr>
 1 NOR    10740117. Yes            NOR
 2 TKM    10726360. No             NOR
 3 SYR    10559247. Yes            SYR
 4 ISR    10317065. No             SYR
 5 DOM    10152261. No             SYR
 6 TJK     9741324. Yes            TJK
 7 YEM     9554599. No             TJK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of 'Yes' have any indication, then get the cumulative sum based on creating a logical vector with 'Yes' and use that as a grouping variable and create the 'nearest' as the `first` value of 'iso3c'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp = cumsum(reported_by_FAO == 'Yes')) %>% 
   mutate(nearest = first(iso3c)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  iso3c production reported_by_FAO nearest
#  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>  
#1 NOR     10740117 Yes             NOR    
#2 TKM     10726360 No              NOR    
#3 SYR     10559247 Yes             SYR    
#4 ISR     10317065 No              SYR    
#5 DOM     10152261 No              SYR    
#6 TJK      9741324 Yes             TJK    
#7 YEM      9554599 No              TJK
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, we can extract the 'No', 'Yes' elements separately, use `findInterval` to get the index and return the corresponding 'iso3c'

```
df1$nearest <- df1$iso3c
ino <- df1$reported_by_FAO == 'No'
iyes <- df1$reported_by_FAO == 'Yes'
df1$nearest[ino] <- sapply(df1$production[ino], function(x) {
     val <- df1$production[iyes]
     df1$iso3c[iyes][order(val)][findInterval(x, val[order(val)]) + 1]
   })
```

-output

```
df1
#  iso3c production reported_by_FAO nearest
#1   NOR   10740117             Yes     NOR
#2   TKM   10726360              No     NOR
#3   SYR   10559247             Yes     SYR
#4   ISR   10317065              No     SYR
#5   DOM   10152261              No     SYR
#6   TJK    9741324             Yes     TJK
#7   YEM    9554599              No     TJK
```

---

Or another option is to get the `abs`olute difference and find the index with `which.min`

```
df1$nearest[ino] <- sapply(df1$production[ino], function(x) {
     val <- df1$production[iyes]
     df1$iso3c[iyes][which.min(abs(val -x))]
   })
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(iso3c = c("NOR", "TKM", "SYR", "ISR", "DOM", "TJK", 
"YEM"), production = c(10740117, 10726360, 10559247, 10317065, 
10152261, 9741324, 9554599), reported_by_FAO = c("Yes", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: This is great! One problem with this approach is that it only chooses the next highest value, as opposed to the closest value. I realise that this still achieves the intended output!

Comment: @prayner I was thinking that the Yes, No column have some indication.  Or is it because of the data example

Comment: @prayner Do you have a case where the first element selects the last row value or is the data already ordered by production

Comment: The Yes/No column is important yes, I edited my initial post. As you guessed, I am trying to mutate a new column which shows the country with the closest numerical production value AND is reported by the FAO.

"Do you have a case where the first element selects the last row value ". Not sure what you mean by this, but the original dataframe is just an extended version of this sample df, with every country in the world and its respective production. Currently, it is sorted by production.

Comment: Hmm it's still giving me the same output ie choosing the next highest country with "Yes". If I remove the ` + 1`, it provides the next lowest.

Comment: @prayner Based on the example you showed, I get the expected as you showed

Comment: @prayner  I am not sure what you meant in your comments when this is looping over the entire 'No' elements separately and matching on the 'Yes' with `findInterval`.  To make this more explicit, I updated with the `abs`olute difference with `which.min`

Comment: You did it! Thank you so much